# I am getting null values for all opportunity fields

Tags: apex, map, after-trigger, null-pointer

I have used a Map to get the Id of the opportunity, but I am not able to access other fields of that opportunity as I am getting null value. Also, getting an error 'Attemp to de-reference a null object'

```
trigger AfterGauAllocation on npsp__Allocation__c (after insert) {

Map<Id,npsp__Allocation__c> nMap = new Map<Id,npsp__Allocation__c>();
Map<Id,npsp__Allocation__c> newMap = new Map<Id,npsp__Allocation__c>();


for(npsp__Allocation__c alloc: trigger.new){
    nMap.put(alloc.Id, alloc);
    newMap.put(alloc.npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c,alloc);
}

List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
List<npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c> gauList = new List<npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c>();


Decimal DynamicAmountOpp; //This is to keep the state of the Amount and not lose the value for multiple opps
Decimal DynamicAmountGau;
for(npsp__Allocation__c newAlloc: trigger.new){
     
    System.debug('nMap: ' + nMap);
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Id = nMap.get(newAlloc.Id).npsp__Opportunity__c);
    System.debug('opp: ' + opp);
    System.debug('opp name ' + opp.Name); // I am getting null value here
    DynamicAmountOpp = opp.Amountlefttoallocate__c; //I am getting null value here
    System.debug('Opp Dynamic Amount left to allocate: ' + DynamicAmountOpp);
    DynamicAmountOpp -= newAlloc.npsp__Amount__c;
    //opp.Amountlefttoallocate__c -= newAlloc.npsp__Amount__c;
    oppList.add(opp);
    
    npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c gau = new npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c(Id = nMap.get(newAlloc.Id).npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c);
    DynamicAmountGau = gau.New_Available_Amount__c;
    System.debug('Dynamic Gau new available amount: ' + DynamicAmountGau);
    DynamicAmountGau += newAlloc.npsp__Amount__c;
    //gau.New_Available_Amount__c += newAlloc.npsp__Amount__c;
    gauList.add(gau);
}
System.debug('opp list to update ' + oppList);
System.debug('Gau list to update ' + gauList);

update oppList;
update gauList;
```

Attached is logs screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data doesn't appear out of nowhere. Executing `Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Id = nMap.get(newAlloc.Id).npsp__Opportunity__c);` doesn't magically get you the other data for the opportunity. You either need to set the data manually, or query for it (if it is an existing record, as it should be in this case).

Trigger context variables (`trigger.new`, `trigger.old`, `trigger.newMap`, and `trigger.oldMap`) do give us all of the field values, but only:

- In triggers (so if you're doing work in a Visualforce controller extension, you can't just use `trigger.new`, it'd be null)
- For the records that fired the trigger
- And only the fields on the trigger object (so no data from parent or child records)

The typical pattern you'll see for this is Aggregate-Query-Update

```java
Set<Id> relatedOppIds = new Set<Id>();

// Aggregate Ids to query (so we don't query inside of a loop)
for(npsp__Allocation__c alloc: trigger.new){
    relatedOppIds.add(alloc.npsp__Opportunity__c);
}

// Query for the data you need, and store it in a map for easy access
Map<Id, Opportunity> relatedOppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name, Amountlefttoallocate__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :relatedOppIds]);

// Process records so you can do your Update(s)
for(npsp__Allocation__c newAlloc: trigger.new){
     
    System.debug('nMap: ' + nMap);
    Opportunity opp = relatedOppMap.get(newAlloc.npsp__Opportunity__c);

    // and so on
}
```

You'll also need to do this to get data for your `npsp__General_Accounting_Unit__c` records as well. Declare another `Set<Id>`, you can add it to the same loop as the one that aggregates Opp Ids. Then it'll be another Map + query.

Comment: Thank you it worked